# Do a diff on parts of a string

Tags: bash, text-processing

Please help a Linux newbie!

I want to compare the output of lsinitrd from 2 different images. Some lines eg

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         2146 Aug  1 01:00 usr/lib/modules/5.18.12-1-default/kernel/lib/crypto/libchacha.ko.zst

-rw-r--r--   1 root     root         2165 Oct 14 16:58 usr/lib/modules/6.0.7-1-default/kernel/lib/crypto/libchacha.ko.zst
```

both refer to different versions of the same file so I would like to ignore those and consider only the files present from one output that are missing in the other.

How can I do this?

Comment: Define "_both refer to different versions of the same file_". For example, I can see that the directory name between `modules/` and `/kernel` is different, but would ignoring that directory name be sufficient? What about `usr/lib/modules/6.0.7-1-default/kernel/lib/crypto/thing.zst` and `usr/lib/modules/6.0.7-1-default/testing/lib/crypto/thing.zst` though?

Comment: @roaima: I will clarify further. Whatever folder the file eg "thing.zst" is located at isn't important. If I find "thing.zst" under different paths, I discard it and focus only on what's missing.

Comment: Can you please clarify the requirement in your question, ideally as if you'd thought of it. It's better to have all the issues in the same place, keeping the comment thread as clean as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like that:

```bash
v1="5.18.12-1-default"
v2="6.0.7-1-default"
diff \
  <(lsinitrd -k "$v1" | grep ' usr/lib/modules/' | sed -e 's#usr/lib/modules/[^/]*#usr/lib/modules/version#' -e 's/^.* //') \
  <(lsinitrd -k "$v2" | grep ' usr/lib/modules/' | sed -e 's#usr/lib/modules/[^/]*#usr/lib/modules/version#' -e 's/^.* //') \
| grep '^[<>]'
```

Launch it with `root` user or prefix each `lsinitrd` command with `sudo` command.

With my versions, I have this result:

```
> usr/lib/modules/version/kernel/drivers/net/mii.ko.xz
> usr/lib/modules/version/kernel/drivers/net/usb
> usr/lib/modules/version/kernel/drivers/net/usb/r8152.ko.xz
> usr/lib/modules/version/kernel/drivers/net/usb/usbnet.ko.xz
> usr/lib/modules/version/kernel/drivers/net/veth.ko.xz
> usr/lib/modules/version/kernel/net/802
> usr/lib/modules/version/kernel/net/802/stp.ko.xz
> usr/lib/modules/version/kernel/net/bridge
> usr/lib/modules/version/kernel/net/bridge/bridge.ko.xz
> usr/lib/modules/version/kernel/net/llc
> usr/lib/modules/version/kernel/net/llc/llc.ko.xz
```

UPDATE

If you want the version id in output, replace `grep` command and it parameter by this `awk` command:

```bash
awk -v v1="$v1" -v v2="$v2" '$0 !~ /^[<>]/ {next} /^>/ {sub("/version/", "/" v1 "/"); print} /^</ {sub("/version/", "/" v2 "/"); print}'
```

My result:

```
> usr/lib/modules/6.0.5-200.fc36.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/mii.ko.xz
> usr/lib/modules/6.0.5-200.fc36.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/usb
> usr/lib/modules/6.0.5-200.fc36.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/usb/r8152.ko.xz
> usr/lib/modules/6.0.5-200.fc36.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/usb/usbnet.ko.xz
> usr/lib/modules/6.0.5-200.fc36.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/veth.ko.xz
> usr/lib/modules/6.0.5-200.fc36.x86_64/kernel/net/802
> usr/lib/modules/6.0.5-200.fc36.x86_64/kernel/net/802/stp.ko.xz
> usr/lib/modules/6.0.5-200.fc36.x86_64/kernel/net/bridge
> usr/lib/modules/6.0.5-200.fc36.x86_64/kernel/net/bridge/bridge.ko.xz
> usr/lib/modules/6.0.5-200.fc36.x86_64/kernel/net/llc
> usr/lib/modules/6.0.5-200.fc36.x86_64/kernel/net/llc/llc.ko.xz
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It works. Thanks.